# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.clear()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, google-maps

When I try to open the Navigation Home the App crashes
[Navigation Home image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT1wV.png)
I have tried initializing the mMap but the app still crashes. Please help me out

My error >
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.clear()' on a null object reference
at com.example.gpshelper.Activity.home$2.onLocationResult(home.java:138)

Here's my Code

```
public class home extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationRequest locationRequest;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    LatLng latLng;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    TextView header_name, header_email;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    String current_uid;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.home_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nev_view);
        //navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        current_uid = firebaseUser.getUid();

        callpermissionlistener();
        update_location();
        dynamicheaderlistener();
    }

    private void dynamicheaderlistener() {

        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        header_name = header.findViewById(R.id.header_name_text);
        header_email = header.findViewById(R.id.header_email_text);

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String current_name = dataSnapshot.child(current_uid).child("firstname").getValue(String.class);
                String current_email = dataSnapshot.child(current_uid).child("email").getValue(String.class);

                String s1 = "Hi "+current_name;
                header_name.setText(s1);
                header_email.setText(current_email);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void update_location() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)== PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)==PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            fusedLocationProviderClient = new FusedLocationProviderClient(this);
            locationRequest = new LocationRequest()
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                    .setInterval(3000) //update interval
                    .setFastestInterval(5000); //fastest interval

            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, new LocationCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                    if (locationResult != null)
                    {
                        mMap.clear();
                        final double lat = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude();
                        final double log = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude();
                        latLng = new LatLng(lat, log);
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("your current location"));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15F));

                        //update latitude and longitude
                        Map <String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
                        update.put("latitude", lat);
                        update.put("longitude", log);
                        databaseReference.child(current_uid).updateChildren(update).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                //Toast.makeText(home.this, "updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(home.this,"location not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            },getMainLooper());
        }
        else
        {
            callpermissionlistener();
        }
    }

    private void callpermissionlistener() {
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
        String rationale = "Please provide location permission so that you can ...";
        Permissions.Options options = new Permissions.Options()
                .setRationaleDialogTitle("location permission")
                .setSettingsDialogTitle("warrning");

        Permissions.check(this, permissions, rationale, options, new PermissionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onGranted() {
                // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
                SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(home.this);
                update_location();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDenied(Context context, ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
                callpermissionlistener();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else {
            backpressedwarrning();
        }
        //super.onBackPressed();
    }
    public void backpressedwarrning(){
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(home.this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message).setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to close this application ?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.setTitle("Exit");
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        
       // LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        //.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nev_home:
                
                startActivity(new Intent(home.this, home.class));
                finish();
                
                break;
            case R.id.nev_profile:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new profilefagment()).commit();
                /*getSupportActionBar().setTitle("profile");
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);*/
                break;
            case R.id.nev_joiningc:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new joincirclefragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nev_invite:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new invitecodefragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nev_mycircle:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new mycirclefragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nev_logout:

                firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (firebaseUser != null)
                {
                    firebaseAuth.signOut();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(home.this, login_screen.class));
                }
                break;
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because somehow before initializing `mMap` from the `onMapReady()`, it called `mMap.clear();`

To prevent the crash, make sure to null-check the `mMap` first and then access it.

For e.g.

```
if (mMap != null) {
    ...
    mMap.clear();
    mMap.addMarker(...);
    mMap. moveCamera(...);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thankyouu for your answer , i finally understand it , I put null check in my update_location method
                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                        if (locationResult != null)
                        {
                            if(mMap != null){

                            mMap.clear();